# Use calculated value for comparison in aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
var data_form = {
  {
    _id : "123",
    result:{
      run:10
    },
    result_re:{
      run:10
    },
    result_ch:{
      run:10
    },
    result_qm:{
      run:10
    }
  },
  {
    _id : "345",
    result:{
      run:20
    },
    result_re:{
      run:20
    },
    result_ch:{
      run:20
    },
    result_qm:{
      run:20
    }
  },
  {
    _id : "567",
    result:{
      run:30
    },
    result_re:{
      run:30
    },
    result_ch:{
      run:30
    },
    result_qm:{
      run:30
    }
  }
}

var pipeline = [
      { $project: { 

          total: { $add: [ "$result.run", "$result_re.run", "$result_ch.run", "$result_qm.run"] } ,               
          discount:{  
                      $cond: [ { $gt: [ total , 50 ] }, 1, 0]
                   }
          }
      },
      { $sort: {total: -1}},
      { $limit : 10 }
]

db.getCollection('game_users').aggregate(pipeline)
```

I need to compare total output with aggregation condition and counter increase if condition match.

My collection is defined in data_form variable.

total field output get from query and if that total is grater than 50 after that counter increase.

Comment: Which are you asking? To compare the value from the expression `$add: [ "$result.run", "$result_re.run", ...` etc to 50? if so just place the same `$add` expression within the `$cond`. You cannot reference the value of another pre-calculated field in the same pipeline stage. Either do it "twice" ( recommended ) or do the `$add` in one `$project` and the `$cond` in a "following" `$project` stage.

Comment: sum of the all field "$result.run", "$result_re.run", "$result_ch.run", "$result_qm.run" get value in total that total value compare with 50 . if greater than 50 increase counter , how that counter increase

Comment: total = result.run(20) + result_re.run(20) + result_ch.run(20) + result_qm.run(20) = 40;
that total value compare with 50.
if 80>50 counter increase else not increase.
that counter value want in final result
for each document check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the expression within the `$cond`. You cannot reference the value of another calculated field within the same pipeline stage. Either do it twice or put in separate stages. The same stage is the most efficient:

```js
var pipeline = [
  { $project: { 
     total: { 
         $add: [ 
           "$result.run",
          "$result_re.run",
          "$result_ch.run",
          "$result_qm.run"
         ]
     } ,               
     discount:{  
       $cond: [
         { $gt: [ 
           { $add: [ 
             "$result.run",
             "$result_re.run",
             "$result_ch.run",
             "$result_qm.run"
           ]},
           50
         ]},
         1,
         0
       ]
     }
  }},
  { $sort: {total: -1}},
  { $limit : 10 }
]
```

Or separate the `$project` in two stages

```js
var pipeline = [
  { $project: { 
     total: { 
         $add: [ 
           "$result.run",
          "$result_re.run",
          "$result_ch.run",
          "$result_qm.run"
         ]
     }
  }},
  { $project: {
     total: 1,
     discount:{  
       $cond: [
         { $gt: [ "$total", 50 ] }
         1,
         0
       ]
     }
  }},

  }}
  { $sort: {total: -1}},
  { $limit : 10 }
]
```

This looks "prettier" but running another stage means another pass through data, so it's probably best to do in one stage.

To get the "totals" across the collection, run a separate aggregation to the paged results.

```js
var pipeline = [
  { $group: { 
     _id: null,
     total: {
       $sum: {
         $add: [ 
           "$result.run",
           "$result_re.run",
           "$result_ch.run",
           "$result_qm.run"
         ]
       }
     } ,               
     discount:{
       $sum: {
         $cond: [
           { $gt: [ 
             { $add: [ 
               "$result.run",
               "$result_re.run",
               "$result_ch.run",
               "$result_qm.run"
             ]},
             50
           ]},
           1,
           0
         ]
       }
     }
  }}
];
```

Do not try and get both the paged results and the total in the same response since that is not how you do it. These should be run separately as attempting to return in one result will certainly break the BSON limit in real world use cases.

Comment: But in need total count of discount . how many times discount counter increase?

Comment: @JayJariwala Increase over what? Total of **all** documents? Your question shows merely a `$project` stage which just works on the current document. You are also applying a `$sort` and `$limit` so you should not have a "total" from all documents in the same aggregate statement. Run a separate aggregate query with `$group` for **all**. The same principles apply to the calculated field.

Comment: @JayJariwala Run another aggregation for the total. I'm showing you the `$group` in the answer, but you need to run this separate to the "paged" results. This is how we have always done this in SQL and NoSQL.